# Find the number of connection points associated with a particular broadband line?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I am living in a house share in a large house with 10 bedrooms. There are a number of different phone lines running into the house, and I have my broadband connection running off one of them.

When I set up the broadband, the only way I could find which port/ phone line socket to plug my router into was by manually going around plugging it into each one until I found the one with the active internet connection.

Now that I have my internet connection up and running, is there a way that I can find out how many other ports there are in the house from which it would be possible to use my internet connection? i.e. is there a way I could find out the number of phone line/ broadband sockets that I could plug a router into, so that, in theory, I could have one router for the ground floor, and another router for the first floor, connecting each router directly to the source, rather than extending my existing wireless network?

I'm wondering if there's a command I can run from the command line on my computer to do this, or something like that? I know I can find out about my network (i.e. the network provided by the router I'm connected to) by using `ipconfig`, but is there a way of finding out the number of active 'ports' (don't know if this is the right word) that are coming from the same source as my connection?

**Edit**

My reason for wanting to utilise as many connection points as I can, rather than have all of us working off the same router/ extended network is in case, for example, several people want to stream online video, or use online gaming- which would make the connection for the rest of us ridiculously slow...

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me. Forget the whole idea & rethink with wifi extenders or wired ethernet between rooms.

Comment: I'm just thinking in terms of usability though too... given that there will be (up to) 10 of us using the connection at any one time, and that one or two people will be 'heavy' users, (i.e. streaming, online gaming, etc), I think all of us working off one 'extended' router would make the connection painfully slow...

Comment: You still haven't considered the basic tenet of your question... what would happen if I plugged 2 modem/routers into one phone line? Which is what makes it an XY problem in the first place.

Comment: @someone2088: Tetsujin is correct. If you connect two ADSL modems to one line all you will do is break the connection for everybody. On the other hand if you think you have multiple independent lines and active ADSL subscriptions on ones you are not using, you have to contact your landlord to find out which ones he's paying for broadband on.

Comment: Oh, ok- thanks. I didn't realise that it wasn't possible to connect two separate modems/ routers to the same broadband connection... Why is this?

Comment: I know that there are multiple independent lines, as when I set up my broadband, and tried pugging the router into one of the connection ports, I couldn't get a connection. After phoning my provider, they told me that there were several lines in the house, and sent someone round with something that they plugged into each one to check if it was active- so I used the first one they found.

Comment: If you want to ask more information, you need to understand/ask how it is  made physically your local network, else the question will be too broad to be answered...